# How to install chaos physics

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine4

I am really interested in chaos physics and went to plugins to see if it was enabled and it is: [image: image stuff] I have looked up tutorials on it and everything and none say how to install it so I assume it is basic. They select on the modes panel but for some reason for there isn't one. Modes is a drop down panel on the same bar as the play button and stuff.[image: stuff] The chaos physics engine isnt one of the options it only has the default. I am on Unreal 4.25.3 windows 10 and this project is blueprints but I prefer to work in c++ blueprints is just better and faster for tests. I have looked at multiple forums and videos and noone seems to have the issue I do which is it just doesn't show up. Could I please get some help on this as it looks amazing and fun. Also if there is an easy way to get the modes selector back where it used to be and not as a dropdown. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, the Chaos Physics Beta is  out since Unreal 4.3 but until its out of beta a source build is required to play around with it. You have to get the demo from the epic games launcher. You will also have to request to join the epic games github and download the unreal engine files, move the ChaosDestructionDemo folder to the same folder that you have your GitHub build in. You then run the GenerateProjectFiles.bat, open the created UE4.sln and then build the ChasoDestructionDemo for Development editor.

This will rebuild the whole engine with the Chaos plugin installed and then you can launch the uproject from the epic games launcher.

There are a lot of details on this forum and a couple of videos that you can have a look at too.
https://forums.unrealengine.com/unreal-engine/announcements-and-releases/1641765-how-to-enable-chaos

If you have any more questions, let me know and ill try my best to help you out.

Hope you have a good time destroying stuff :)